# Circular git problems

Tags: eclipse, git

We have a git project in Eclipse.  There is a .classpath file.  This is unfortunately different for each developer because we have different machines.

We therefore added .classpath to .gitignore.
Now, when one of our developers does a git pull, it says Error, .classpath needs to be merged.
We cannot add it, because it isn't in the project.  We can't merge it, it isn't in the project.

DIRTY INDEX: proj/.classpath

I apologize for the repeat questions, we are going in circles.  I don't know why git is so hard.  I've never seen problems like this in mercurial, svn, or cvs.  It seems nightmarishly complicated.

In desperation, we are just removing .classpath from .gitignore, adding .classpath, and then hopefully:

```
git add .classpath
git pull
git commit -m"I hate git"
```

will work.  Of course this means that every commit could have .classpath in it, which is also screwed up.

If a file is in .gitignore, how can git possibly tell us it needs to be merged?  The whole point is to LEAVE US ALONE!

Comment: Was the file being tracked before being added to the .gitignore?

Comment: Yes, it was tracked, and then we did a:

git rm -r -cache .classpath

Comment: and you committed after doing `git rm --cached`?

Comment: I committed after giving up on being able to get rid of it.  I figured better to add a newer classpath and at least be able to successfully merge.

Answer (score 0):

That's because he has to resolve the conflict that exists because he has a local change to class path at the same time that he's receiving the ignore.

Consider what this would be if it were a source file.  You're saying to ignore it, but locally on his branch he had changes on it.  If git just blew the file away you could have lost your work.

Before you blame `git`, perhaps you should consider reading the documentation, git-scm.com/book/ so that you understand how git works and is supposed to be used.  This would be in contrast to trying random things blindly hoping that they 'do the job'.  `Git` is NOT `CVS`, `SVN`, or `Mercurial` there is nothing inherently hard about it.  If anything the problem here is more with Eclipse then with Git.

Another way around this? Copy the file to another location temporarily.  Then restore the .classpath file so that it is identical to what is commited. Now you should be able to pull properly. Afterwards just restore the file and you should be good..

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  There isn't anything on the server for .classpath.  We delete .classpath, do a git pull, and it says there is a merge problem.  What is there to merge?  It's not like I haven't tried reading the documentation.  I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: I never said it was on the server.  The problem is that your user made changes to his local version of the file, which on his branch is still tracked.  Those changes are conflicting with the file's deletion that occurs during the merge.. `Pull` is a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.  If you can specify which part of what I'm saying you don't understand it might be helpful